# Measure of Angle for an isosceles triangle between parallel lines

Tags: geometry, angle

[image]

Two lines are parallel and there is a transverse line passing through both.  There is an isosceles triangle as shown in the figure.  angle x measurement is given as 8, and the problem is to find out angle y.  Can anybody help please.  I can only see a solution when angle abc is 90 degrees, but the question does not mention that.  Is there any rule/theorem saying that it is 90 degrees?  If not, how do I solve it.

Comment: From what I can see there is no solution.  You have shown that there with the additional information of the measure of angle B, you could solve this.  Show that for different B, you get different y.

Comment: You are missing information. Something more should be given, like the angle $\angle \, ABC$ or $\angle \, BAC$.